# Pi stuck at boot with weird nerdy facts about stack limit

Tags: pi-3, boot

I have got pi 3B and it stucks at boot up. However when I use the same SD card and power supply with another pi 3B, it works.
[image]
**Updated:**
Which doesn't work

[image][image]

Which works
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we have photos of the front and back of the machine which works and the machine which does not work?

Comment: I had similar issues after I shortened some pins which are not 5V tolerant with the 5V pins. The Pi seems to start but freezes at boot, cannot load things or greets me with a kernel panic. My Pi is just physically damaged beyond repair. Did you do things with the GPIO pins and maybe damaged it accidentally?

Comment: @kwasmich yes I believe so. I have got 4 of them burnt while making robots. I never exactly found out where I got wrong but I believe I must have shortened pins. Was just trying my luck after an year if I could fix them. I am studying electronic engg so I was wondering if I could fix. Only if I knew what component is malfunctioning

Comment: @joan added in question

Comment: "I have got 4 of them burnt " - if you omit vital information from your question what do you expect?

Comment: clearly you need more dust on the one that doesn't work, because it seems there's a ton of dust on the one that works - :p

Comment: If you've set any overclocking etc in config.txt, remove them, or try creating a fresh install without changing config.txt at all - "Internal Error: oops: 5" is hard to search for (well, too hard for me, because it's not my problem so I don't really care that much)